# Combining indicators and correcting to one scale

Tags: pine-script, indicator, pine-script-v5

Im trying to combine two indicators into one panel.

Problem is, indicator A's scale is 0 to 100 while indicator B's scale is -100 to 100

What kind of equation could change the final value of either indicator to match the other? Preferably to indicator A's scale of 0 to 100.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rescale()` function as described [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-rescale-an-indicator-from-one-scale-to-another).

```
// ————— When the scale of the signal to rescale is known (bounded).
rescale(_src, _oldMin, _oldMax, _newMin, _newMax) =>
    // Rescales series with known min/max.
    // _src            : series to rescale.
    // _oldMin, _oldMax: min/max values of series to rescale.
    // _newMin, _newMin: min/max values of rescaled series.
    _newMin + (_newMax - _newMin) * (_src - _oldMin) / max(_oldMax - _oldMin, 10e-10)
```

If you don't know the max and min values, you can use the `normalize()` function.

```
// ————— When the scale of the signal to rescale is unknown (unbounded).
// Min/Max of signal to rescale is determined by its historical low/high.
normalize(_src, _min, _max) =>
    // Normalizes series with unknown min/max using historical min/max.
    // _src      : series to rescale.
    // _min, _min: min/max values of rescaled series.
    var _historicMin =  10e10
    var _historicMax = -10e10
    _historicMin := min(nz(_src, _historicMin), _historicMin)
    _historicMax := max(nz(_src, _historicMax), _historicMax)
    _min + (_max - _min) * (_src - _historicMin) / max(_historicMax - _historicMin, 10e-10)
```